# how to read file using fs in node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

I'm tring to read this file in nodejs using fs module.
I'm getting the response twice. let me know what am i doing wrong. Here's my code.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('sample.txt', function(err, sampleData) {
    console.log(String(sampleData));
    //res.end();
    });
  console.log("The end");
  // res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
}).listen(2000);
```

After hitting the port in browser. I'm getting the response twice in my terminal. Here's the output.

```
The end
this is sample text for the testing.

The end
this is sample text for the testing.
```

Comment: The code won't work. And the result does not fit to it.

Comment: sample.txt contains "this is sample text for the testing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely getting it twice because you are accessing http://localhost:2000/ from the browser.

When doing so there are actually two requests being made. Your actual request and the favicon :) both of which are handled by your server. 

Have a look into Chrome debugger -> Network

[image]

Comment: Oh.. now i get it.

Answer (score 2):

Two log messages will appear: one for / and one for /favicon.ico

You can verify this by adding console.log(req.url);

To avoid this:

```
    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");

    http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url === '/'){  // or if(req.url != '/faicon.ico'){
        fs.readFile('sample.txt', function(err , sampleData){
            console.log(String(sampleData));
            res.end();
        });
    console.log("The end");
    }

    // res.writeHead(200);
}).listen(2000);
```

Comment: this condition worked for me >>if(req.url != '/favicon.ico')

Answer (score 1):

A request is made to favicon.io automatically.
To avoid automatic request to favicon, you can do the following

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url != '/favicon.ico'){
        fs.readFile('sample.txt', function(err , sampleData){
            console.log(String(sampleData));
            res.end();
        });
       console.log("The end");
    }

}).listen(2000);
```

O/p =>

```
The end.
this is sample text for the testing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may *pipe* the file to the client:

```
fs.createReadStream('sample.txt').pipe(res);
```

Comment: I want to view the response in terminal console. I'm getting the res twice. I just want to know why am i getting it twice.